# Safe gaming, banking and development on the same machine

Tags: windows, security, virtual-machine

I'm looking for a way to keep a gaming pc and a work pc. Currently i have a quite powerful machine: i7, 32gb ram, 2x420gb ssd internal (and some other external ssd)

Basically the gaming pc will be only used for gaming and i normally install dodgy software so it might get infected.

But i still want to do some work and banking login. So i can't use this OS.

Requirements:

- Windows 10
- don't get infected from the gaming pc
- safe os where i can have confidential information
- a way to access banking websites
- a way to develop software

I was thinking of the following options:

Option 1: OS on external ssd

I'll have an OS for work and banking only installed on an external SSD, so i can use on my laptop as well.

I'd like to encrypt this SSD somehow, i think the default Windows 10 encryption should be enough. The issue is I'm not sure i can encrypt the os partition so it might not work.

Another problem is that i need to block access to the internal ssd otherwise my work osmight get infected. I might try to encrypt them, but not sure is safe.

Here I'm also a bit worried that my development environment might get compromised while i install some random package (npm node modules).

Option 2

Same as option 1 but create a vm for Banking and a vm for development. The main Windows installation will not do anything.

Any other suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! I must live in a *dangerous* zone because I do gaming, access my bank website and develop on the same computer. You just need to be careful. But, if you already have 2 possible solutions why are you asking for another suggestions?

Comment: Because I'm not sure is a real solution. I'm not an expert in security and i might be missing something fundamental. Also there might be way better and simpler ways of doing the same thing.